# Problem installing the GO SDK

Tags: go-sdk

In https://github.com/stellar/go/tree/master/clients/horizonclient i can see that i have to execute go get but

```
# github.com/stellar/go/price
go/src/github.com/stellar/go/price/main.go:172:12: undefined: bits.Mul64
go/src/github.com/stellar/go/price/main.go:178:10: undefined: bits.Div64
go/src/github.com/stellar/go/price/main.go:193:12: undefined: bits.Mul64
go/src/github.com/stellar/go/price/main.go:194:15: undefined: bits.Add64
go/src/github.com/stellar/go/price/main.go:201:10: undefined: bits.Div64
```

this is what i get. It's an compilation error. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: What is the output of `go version`?

Comment: It's go1.11.2 linux/amd64

Comment: The prerequisites list v1.12 as a minimum. Not saying upgrading will definitely fix it, but it's worth a shot.